# Is software like tune up utilities essential?

Tags: performance, performance-tuning

Is software like tune up utilities necessary? Can't we perform the tasks using some other free ware tools and built in windows tools?

Comment: It is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

The use of these tools is nto essential, but by using this type of application - old files, services, fragments etc which can slow down your machine can be removed which keeps your computer performing better.

There are a lot of freeware and builtin tools which can be used to optimise your PC.

Freeware includes CCLeaner, Glary, TuneUp, CleanMaster, WiseReg.. there are loads.

Builtin Windows Utilities include:

**Disk Cleanup** - deletes unwanted files and temp

**Chkdsk** - Checks your disk for errors and recovers file fragments

**msconfig** - stops unwanted services from starting with your computer

**Disk Defrag** - defragments your drive

**Security Essentials** (not builtin, but MS anyway) will scan for viruses, spyware etc which could be slowing down your machine

**IE Control Panel** - can be used to wipe IE history, session info etc - keeping your machine clean

Some of these will accomplish some of the tasks required to keep your machine in top condition

Other advice on keeping your computer running well and in good condition I could give includes:

- Regular updating of windows to avoid security holes and potentially improve performance
- Regular disk cleanups/defrags to keep the machines drive litter-free
- Regular AV scanning to keep your machine in good health
- Regular Reboots of your computer - "turn it off and on again" really does work!

Most of these tasks can be run on a schedule using the windows task scheduler to take the work away from yourself.

Comment: Using such a program means you don´t have to remember all the built in options and makes accessing things like the start-up manager easier. I find "TweakNow" quicker as I only use it every month or so. Others will have their favourites!

Comment: While this is very true Brian, there are a lot of environments (schools & colleges, work placements) where licensing prohibit this - so these tools are amazing and very quick & useful - but not always a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

I have Win 8.1, and I had the same question like you. With Win 3.1, 95, 97, XP I used similar software a lot. Now, since Win 7, I simplified things down, and don't use them anymore.

I run CCLeaner occasionally, and the rest is done by Windows' built in tools running in the background automatically. I find that about 10 years ago the freeware tools were really necessary, but over time Windows got most of the helpful features covering 80% of the needs. Like I used Diskeeper to defragment on XP, but Win 8.1 trims the SSD automatically, and the built in Defragment feature is good enough.

As Fazer87 says, I experience that at least a weekly reboot improves a lot.